# How to code for a pattern in a sequence by group in R

Tags: r

Sample data

```r
df<- data.frame (Part_ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
DateSample=c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-15", "2022-01-22", "2022-01-29","2022-02-01","2022-02-06","2022-02-08","2022-02-20","2022-02-22"),
Result=c("A","B","B","B","A","B","A","B","A","A"),
n_of_A=c(1,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,3),
n_of_samples=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I have a large dataset of sequential samples taken from participants with either an abnormal result (A) or a normal result (B).

I need to work out which participants had distinct episodes of result A.
An episode of A is considered ended if (any number of) A result(s) is followed by at least 3 B results or a 28 day interval between abnormal results. Ultimately I only want to include the A samples from the first A episode for each participant so need to find a way to exclude any A result samples that come from these second (or greater) A episodes.

So my aims are

- identify those participants with multiple episodes of A (noting that the number of samples and pattern in which they appear vary for each participant)
- identify any samples with result A occurring subsequent to the first episode so that I can exclude them in a further analysis (I need to keep all the B samples for each participant even if they have a second A episode)

I think the desired output is the following (but happy to consider any other way of achieving this):

```r
df<- data.frame (Part_ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 DateSample=c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-15", "2022-01-22", "2022-01-29","2022-02-01","2022-02-06","2022-02-08","2022-02-20","2022-02-22"),
                 Result=c("A","B","B","B","A","B","A","B","A","A"),
                 n_of_A=c(1,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,3),
                 n_of_samples=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                 more_than_one_A_episode=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                 sample_from_new_A_episode=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I have tried determining whether there were 3 intervening B results between A results 1 and 2 for a given participant using the following which I think worked in my large dataset to identify which participants had this occurring.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
df%>%
group_by(Part_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    intervening_3_negs=
      case_when((n_of_samples[n_of_A==2])>(n_of_samples[n_of_A==1]+3)~1, TRUE~0,))
#> Error in UseMethod("group_by"): no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

but I think I need an approach that goes through each participant's samples chronologically and makes a decision at the point of each result A based on what follows.
For a given participant, is this result A the end of an episode? then designate all result As that follow as likely not first episode.

Is there a way of doing this?

(Edited for clarity after some sleep!)

Comment: I don't really have time to make a full answer, but check out `?rle` and `?data.table::rleid` - if you're looking at identifying runs of `"B"` values and then `"A"` values, run-length-encoding can be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly convoluted, but happy to provide something in case it could be helpful. I'm not entirely sure this is what you're looking for.

As mentioned by @thelatemail, use of `rle` and `rleid` can be helpful here.

Here I first used `rleid` to add unique ids to each group of `Result`. So the 3 B's in a row would have the same id. The `rleid` column I created is left in, so you can see how it works. This is done after grouping by `Part_ID`, so ids restart with each new `Part_ID`.

Then, you can group by both `Part_ID` and the new `rleid` and count up how many are in each of these ids. While `rle` does this as well, I thought this was easier to deal with here by add `n()` for the count.

After that, I added a column to indicate when the last date was for a particular result. This makes it easier to detect differences between abnormal tests of 28 days.

Finally, for each `Part_ID` I created an `episode` column that would increase when a new abnormal test is found, after either (1) 3 or more normal tests, or (2) 28 days have elapsed since the last abnormal test.

Once you have the `episode` number, you can easily create your columns to indicate more than 1 episode, and which samples came from a new episode.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(DateSample = as.Date(DateSample)) %>%
  group_by(Part_ID) %>%
  mutate(rleid = rleid(Result)) %>%
  group_by(rleid, .add = T) %>%
  mutate(Count = n()) %>%
  group_by(Part_ID, Result) %>%
  mutate(LastDateSameResult = lag(DateSample, default = first(DateSample))) %>%
  group_by(Part_ID) %>%
  mutate(episode = rleid(Result == "A" & 
                           ((lag(Result, default = "B") == "B" & lag(Count, default = 0) >= 3) |
                              DateSample - LastDateSameResult >= 28))) %>%
  mutate(more_than_1_episode = +(any(episode > 1)),
         sample_from_new_A_episode = +(episode > 1))
```

**Output**

```
   Part_ID DateSample Result n_of_A n_of_samples rleid Count LastDateSameResult episode more_than_1_episode sample_from_new_A_episode
     <dbl> <date>     <chr>   <dbl>        <dbl> <int> <int> <date>               <int>               <int>                     <int>
 1       1 2022-01-01 A           1            1     1     1 2022-01-01               1                   1                         0
 2       1 2022-01-08 B           0            2     2     3 2022-01-08               1                   1                         0
 3       1 2022-01-15 B           0            3     2     3 2022-01-08               1                   1                         0
 4       1 2022-01-22 B           0            4     2     3 2022-01-15               1                   1                         0
 5       1 2022-01-29 A           2            5     3     1 2022-01-01               2                   1                         1
 6       2 2022-02-01 B           0            1     1     1 2022-02-01               1                   0                         0
 7       2 2022-02-06 A           1            2     2     1 2022-02-06               1                   0                         0
 8       2 2022-02-08 B           0            3     3     1 2022-02-01               1                   0                         0
 9       2 2022-02-20 A           2            4     4     2 2022-02-06               1                   0                         0
10       2 2022-02-22 A           3            5     4     2 2022-02-20               1                   0                         0
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this as a framework to approach - it has really helped me and introduced me to lag too. I'm still trying to get it to work for my data but this is definitely a helpful step in the right direction.

Comment: @kema Glad it was helpful. If you want (and can), take a portion of your data using something like `dput(head(df, 100))` for 100 rows, and copy/paste the result in your original post. I would be happy to try to see what else might be needed to get this to work.

Comment: @kema That would help in identifying cases where there are problems. Or, feel free to describe what else may be needed to get this to work...